# How to pick a namespace for individual developers?

Tags: php, namespaces, semantics

How do you pick a namespace for a project when you're just doing it as an open source project.

As an example I'm developing a library for a government department that are supplying open data. The library will be called `RWS`.

Two options are `gerbenjacobs\RWS` or `RWS\RWS`. So either the name of the developer or the department involved, but neither feel semantically correct. This library is going to be for everyone.

How should I namespace this?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem. This type of question might be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yep, when I summarized the last question I had a feeling that the question in itself would be too subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will develop and maintain this app, use the author prefix,
else use a company or department prefix.

```
\author\software
\author\software\package

\company\software
\company\software\package
```

Namespace use-cases as examples:

1. **Symfony**
   They use a subnamespace "Component", just to have a clear folder structure.

   `namespace Symfony\Component\BrowserKit;`
2. **Zend**
   They use Company\Component.

   `namespace Zend\Authentication;`

But my suggestion would be to use `namespace RWS\PackageOne;`.

**Keep in mind that the namespace reflects your folder structure (PSR)!**

Answer (score 1):

The one using your name is a pretty safe way of avoiding collisions, at least in the development phase. 
If no-one can think of a better namespace naming system, leave it as is. Or use a description of what your specific namespace deals with, like email_sorting_module or some such. Don't make problems for yourself.